# JavaScript function argument auto-increments

Tags: javascript, function

I am building a NodeJS web scraper that has to loop over the data in a table row. I have found that the following two code snippets somehow exhibit the same behavior. In the first scenario how is `i` getting incremented?

I have searched for auto-incrementing variables or arguments in JavaScript and found nothing so far.

If it matters, this code is inside a request callback, and I am using cheerio to parse the html.

Snippet 1

```
$(this).find('td span').each(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
});
```

Snippet 2

```
$(this).find('td span').each(function(i) {
     console.log(i);
     i++;
});
```

Comment: If this is DOM (using jQuery or equivalent) then this isn't specific to Node.JS.

Comment: He said he is using cheerio, which is a node module.

Comment: @Sukima you're correct — removed `node.js` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the documentation for `.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) points out, the argument to the function is the index. So jQuery is calling your function with the appropriate index every time — and jQuery is the one keeping track of the index.

In the second example when you do `i++` it actually has no effect on jQuery's original counter that jQuery is keeping track of because it is just getting passed again to your function when the next item is iterated over.

More generally, if you have a function being called with a primitive datatype argument (like a number, a string, etc.)

```
function f(x) {
    // change x here
}
```

That won't have effect on `x` after that particular function call has returned. So:

```
function f(x) {
    x ++;
    console.log(x);
}
var num = 1;
f(num); // the function will log 2 
console.log(num); // num is still 1, though
```

When so-called *"primitives"* (numbers, strings, ...) are passed to a function, only the **value** is being passed, so the function is basically dealing with a copy.

When you pass an object, a *reference* to that object is being passed, which means the function is dealing with the same original object (and thus can modify it).

Comment: P.S., @CambridgeMike, I went ahead and edited the answer with some rephrasing/examples. I hope you don't mind! Excellent response time, by the way.

Comment: note that this also happens for map, where you get (element, index)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the jQuery documentation, it should become clear (I know you said you're using cheerio, but they work the same way).

For the `.each` method, you pass in a callback function. That function is called for each element in your jQuery (or cheerio, whatever) collection, and the index of each element is passed in as the first argument to the callback function.

So, to answer your question, cheerio is incrementing that variable to match the index of the current element it is iterating over.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps some code can help:

```js
var values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

$.each(values, function(index, value) {
  console.log('My value is "' + value + '" and index is ' + index + '.');
});

// Is mostly equivalent to:

function myEach(array, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback(i, array[i]);
  };
}

myEach(values,  function(index, value) {
  console.log('My value is "' + value + '" and index is ' + index + '!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: code without useful commentary or explanation is usually frowned upon here

Comment: Yeah, figured @CambridgeMike answered it better while I was editing this one so I gave up. Probably shoudn't have done that.

Comment: you can always delete it if you're not happy with the answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(this).find('td span').each(function(i) {
    this.ctr = this.ctr || 0;  // initialize ctr
    this.ctr++;
    console.log(ctr);  // 1, 2, 3, 4,....... 
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I still do not follow how this increments `i`. Are arguments in JS functions within `.each()` automatically counters?

Comment: this statement initializes this.ctr with a value of 0.  If this.ctr already exists, it maintains its value otherwise, it is set to 0.